# Content processor is not available in properties of dude model

Tags: c#, xna, fbx

I am using content processor to process the fbx file. My model has no texture but has bones and weights. When I run my code to print model, it is telling "No skinning data"

Later I changed the model to `dude.fbx` model given by Microsoft. Still the error message is same then I checked for content processor in properties of Dude model.

My content processor name is `skinnedboneprocessor`, it is not present in the drop down list of Content Processor. Previously it was set to "Model-XNA Framework".

My content processor should be present in that drop down list how to do it ?

```
    [ContentProcessor]
    public class skinnedboneprocessor : ModelProcessor
    {
        public override ModelContent Process(NodeContent input, ContentProcessorContext context)
        {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake of not adding the reference.

Just make sure that your content Processor's reference is added in your Main projects Content file.

And even make sure that build order is correct.